# Scale and transformation point

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, animate-cc

Facing problem with scaling Text or Movieclip using transformation tool.
all I want to do is creating motion tween to make zoom effect by down scaling the movieclip at the beginning then scale it back to 100%.

After doing this and adding some extra frames to the end, the movieclip shifted from its original place and the transformation point went from center to one of the corners causing the shape shifting.

I wonder if anyone could help and tell me how to solve this.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controls might be botched, but code should still work.  Simply apply a tween to your `TextField` or `MovieClip`.

**Single Box**

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import fl.transitions.*;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import flash.events.Event;

// A demonstration box
var box:Sprite = new Sprite();
box.graphics.beginFill(0xFF);
box.graphics.drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
box.graphics.endFill();
addChild(box)
box.x = box.y = 100;
box.addEventListener("click", animateIn);

function animateIn(e:Event):void {
    // Animate the X then the Y scale.
    var anim:Tween = new Tween(box, "scaleX", Regular.easeOut, 1, 0.5, 1, true);
    new Tween(box, "scaleY", Regular.easeOut, 1, 0.5, 1, true);

    // Listen for the end of the animation, before running the second half.
    anim.addEventListener("motionFinish", animateOut);
}

function animateOut(e:Event):void {
    new Tween(box, "scaleX", Regular.easeOut, 0.5, 1, 1, true);
    new Tween(box, "scaleY", Regular.easeOut, 0.5, 1, 1, true);
}
```

---

**Multiple Boxes**

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import fl.transitions.*;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import flash.events.Event;

var size:int = 40;
var columns:int = Math.floor(stage.stageWidth / size);
var rows:int = Math.floor(stage.stageHeight / size);

// Create demo boxes
var last:Sprite = null;
for (var c:int = 0; c < columns; c++) {
    for (var r:int = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        var box:Sprite = new Sprite();
        box.graphics.beginFill(0xFF);
        box.graphics.drawRect(-size/2 + 1, -size/2 + 1, size - 2, size - 2);
        box.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(box)

        box.x = c*size + size/2;
        box.y = r*size + size/2;
        box.addEventListener("mouseOver", animateIn);
    }
}

function animateIn(e:Event):void {
    var box:Sprite = e.currentTarget as Sprite;

    // Animate the X then the Y scale.
    var anim:Tween = new Tween(box, "scaleX", Regular.easeOut, 1, 0.5, 0.35, true);
    new Tween(box, "scaleY", Regular.easeOut, 1, 0.5, 0.35, true);

    // Listen for the end of the animation, before running the second half.
    anim.addEventListener("motionFinish", animateOut);
}

function animateOut(e:Event):void {
    new Tween(e.currentTarget.obj, "scaleX", Regular.easeOut, 0.5, 1, 0.35, true);
    new Tween(e.currentTarget.obj, "scaleY", Regular.easeOut, 0.5, 1, 0.35, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, actually I need to apply this tween for tens of images and text fields, and adding this code for each could be time-consuming and really frustrating. I agree with you there's something wrong with controls so I'd be grateful, if anyone could have another technique or workaround to apply zoom effect without having this shifting problem.

Comment: Updated with multiple box animation. ;)